# Tee a Pipe Asynchronously

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to write the same information to two pipes, but I don't want to wait for the first pipe to read.  Here's an example

```
mkfifo one
mkfifo two
echo hi | tee one two &
cat one &
cat two &
```

`cat one` does not start reading until `cat two` is run.  Is there a way to make `cat one` run without waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: Fifos are **blocking until opened for reading**. So just open a read FD on them:

```
mkfifo one two
echo hi | tee one two &
exec 3<one
exec 4<two
cat <&3
cat <&4
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the input to tee is bigger than the pipe buffer. Reproduce: change the second line with `dd if=<(yes) count=1000 | tee one two > /dev/null &` and the script will block

Answer (score 0):

```
echo hi | tee one | tee two &
```

Comment: interesting.  I actually wanted either cat one and cat two to be independent.